# Why doesn't `best_estimator_.get_params()` agree with `best_params_`

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am playing around with some scikit-learn objects and I have stumbled upon the following result while trying to tune the hyperparameters. The output of this bit of code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


class NaiveBayesClassifier(Pipeline):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            [("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer()), ("clf", MultinomialNB()),]
        )

    def tune(self, data, min_df, max_df, max_features):
        gs = GridSearchCV(
            estimator=self,
            param_grid={
                "tfidf__max_df": max_df,
                "tfidf__min_df": min_df,
                "tfidf__max_features": max_features,
            },
            verbose=10,
        )

        return gs.fit(*data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

    categories = ["alt.atheism", "soc.religion.christian", "comp.graphics", "sci.med"]
    twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(
        subset="train", categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=42
    )

    nb = NaiveBayesClassifier()

    tuned_model = nb.tune(
        (twenty_train.data, twenty_train.target),
        min_df=[0, 0.1],
        max_df=[0.9, 1],
        max_features=[2_000, 5_000],
    )

    print(tuned_model.best_score_)
    for k, v in tuned_model.best_params_.items():
        print(f"{v}    <>    {tuned_model.best_estimator_.get_params()[k]}")
```

is the following

```
0.9437278025233994
0.9    <>    1.0
5000    <>    None
0    <>    1
```

Looking at the output generated by the grid search, I can see that the parameters on the left indeed produce that average score over the 5 folds. Hence it seems that `tuned_model.best_params_` is what I would expect. However, the parameters of the 
`best_estimator_` are just the default ones.

What is the cause of this? The `Pipeline` class has a `set_params` method, which seems to do the right thing with `tuned_model.best_estimator_.set_params(tuned_model.best_params_)` (but of course now only the parameters are optimal while the model isn't).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like subclassing doesn't play nicely with `sklearn.base.clone`, since the result of calling `get_params` on the subclass is different from the result of the same method called on an actual instance of `Pipeline` (as of version 0.22).

In order to make a proper sklearn estimator, the `__init__` method must declare the parameters as explicit keyword arguments. The override `def __init__(self)` is effectively creating an estimator with no parameters. This explains why `get_params(deep=False)` returns an empty `dict`.

The following subclass works

```
class NaiveBayesClassifier(Pipeline):
    def __init__(self, steps=[], memory=None, verbose=False):
        super().__init__(
            steps or [("tfidf", TfidfVectorizer()), ("clf", MultinomialNB())]
        )

    def tune(self, data, min_df, max_df, max_features):
        gs = GridSearchCV(
            estimator=self,
            param_grid={
                "tfidf__max_df": max_df,
                "tfidf__min_df": min_df,
                "tfidf__max_features": max_features,
            },
            verbose=10,
        )

        return gs.fit(*data)
```

Whilst this now works as intended, the signature of `__init__` is "ugly" as in principle it shouldn't accept any parameters.